# issue with django context processor

Tags: django

Context processor does not work when href inside templates redirect to details

context_processor.py

```html
from .models import Category


def  polls_category(request):
 for e in Category.objects.all():
   name=e.title
   return {"polls_category":name}
```

Context_processor in settings.py

```html
 'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'products.context_processors.polls_category'
            ],
        },
```

Template

```html
{% for obj in gili_list %}

<p><small><a href='{{obj.get_absolute_url}}'>{{polls_category}}</a></small></p>
{% endfor %}
```

views.py

```html
class CategoryListView(ListView):
 model = Category

 template_name = "products/product_list.html"

 def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):

  context = super(CategoryListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)

  context['gili_list'] = Category.objects.all()
  return context
```

models.py

```html
class Category(models.Model):
 title = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)
 slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
 description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
 
 active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
 timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, change your view in views.py to remove the get_context_data method, if you are using a context processor to put context in your navbar, you do not need this extra context. Then add a detail view as below (I am assuming your detail template will be called "product_detail.html"). You will need to import 'DetailView' if you haven't already:

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView

class CategoryListView(ListView):
    model = Category
    template_name = "products/product_list.html"

class CategoryDetailView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'products/product_detail.html'
    model = Category
    context_object_name = 'category'
```

Secondly, change your template, remove 'gili_list' and replace with 'polls_catagory', which is context coming from your context_processors.py, as below:

**product_list.html**

```
{% for obj in polls_category %}

<p><small><a href='{{obj.get_absolute_url}}'>{{ obj.title }}</a></small></p>

{% endfor %}
```

Thirdly, modify your models.py with a 'get_absolute_url' method. I've also added an '**str**' method to make it look better in Django admin. Make sure you import 'reverse':

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class Category(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)
slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('category_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.title}'
```

Fourthly:
Your context processor is now doing something, it is supplying polls_category to every page, and hence to your navbar:

**context_processors.py**

```
def polls_category(request):
    polls_category = Category.objects.all()
    return {"polls_category": polls_category}
```

Fifthly, in the detail template, add in this to check the context is coming through:

**product_detail.html**

```
{{ category.title }} <br>
{{ category.active }}
```

This is all working perfectly at my end. 
Getting the correct object in your product_detail.html is done via the slug in the url, plus "Django magic".

Comment: thank you,  I want to use `<p><small><a href='{{obj.get_absolute_url}}'>{{ obj.title }}</a></small></p>` into every page but  link works only in (http://127.0.0.1:8000/categories/)  i want user to select categories into every page i put href='{{ obj.get_absolute_url }}' inside the navbar,

Comment: I've edited the answer in response to your comments. Please note that I need more info about where these navbar links are going.

Comment: `urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', CategoryListView.as_view(), name='categories'),
     url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', CategoryDetailView.as_view(), 
      name='category_detail'),
),
] ` i want to href to redirect to category_detail

Comment: I've modified to answer to fit your urls.

Comment: Hi @mwayungi is there some reason you haven't accepted this as the correct answer?